# NSFetchedResults Controller blocking UI when updating uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios6, nsfetchedresultscontroller

The update of uitableview with nsfetchedresultscontroller blocks the ui till the data gets loaded.I need to avoid it.Can you please suggest ways to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good article in "Cocoa is My Girlfriend" Site about Coredata and Threads. Exactly this problem has been adressed, that one can update uitableview in background.

http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

Comment: Tried it...but did not get much change compared to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

create a background queue like  and Put ur code in

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // put NSFetchedResults code here
});
```

This will ton block UI

Comment: This cannot be done as updating ui needs to be done only on the main thread.

Comment: yes .. u r right but i said only fetch the data in background queue. i dint said to update UI in background queue

Comment: I am doing fetching in the background only.But when i save the image in core data,it automatically triggers fetchedresultscontroller which reloads the uitableview.During saving & reloading,ui gets blocked.